# Overleaf Compile Error but works fine on ShareLatex

Tags: errors, enumerate, sharelatex, overleaf, compiling

I'm using Overleaf because my group members want to use this platform. Now, I get this weird compile error which doesn't appear on ShareLatex.

**Code**

```
\begin{document}
\maketitlepage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\input{Text/Labo1}
\end{document}
```

**Error Message**

> LaTeX Error: \begin{enumerate} on input line 67 ended by \end{do
>   cument}.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> l.73 \end{document}

**Line 67 is empty in my code!**
I've never used the enumerate command. What is happening here?!

Comment: Line 67 most likely refers to the line within `Text/Labo1.tex`.

Comment: How can we replicate this problem? We need to do that in order to address your issue. At the moment, with only a small code snippet, it is not possible.

Comment: @Werner, indeed! I've checked in Text/Labo1.tex! Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because seemingly the OP fixed the error as suggested in the comments.

Comment: @Werner -- can you enter a brief answer, for the record, and then i'll vote to close.  this is the sort of confusion suffered by a lot of new users.

Answer (score 2):

The error pointing to line 67 is dependent on the current file being processed by (La)TeX. Since your source/main document only has a couple of lines, it must stem from the `\input`ted file `Text/Labo1.tex`.